# Grails Spring-security-ui plugin, not using password encryption

Tags: spring, security, grails

So, I have been making an app, got the back end sorted, generated the user,role and userRole classes in the spring-security-core plugin,within a domain plugin, then used the override command on s2ui to make the login and register controllers, within the main app.

I have the email verification working perfectly and when I bootstrap my admin and customer users and roles, I can log in perfectly.

But if i register a user, and then click on the email link, it logs me in using that, but if I log out and try to log back in, it does not recognise the password.

I am using grails 4.0.5 with jvm 1.8, with the security-core plugin: 4.0.3 and security-ui plugin: 4.0.0.M1.

If there is any more info needed then please let me know, I have probably missed something silly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Title states that passwords are unecrypted. The content of post states that you have problem with authentication. What actually is stored in the db?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc, when I go to the user controller(I am using postgres and I haven't figured out how to get the 'user' table to return rows yet), it shows the password in plaintext, rather than the {bcrypt} format that it does for my admin user (which is bootstrapped through my admin app rather than, my main app), implying that the security-core is encoding using bcrypt, but security-ui is not.

I am also getting an exception when i try to login using said registered user:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null".

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I have a feeling that I need to set a PasswordEncoder, but I am having trouble finding that in the core and UI plugin documentation?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc the documentation for the UI plugin stated that if you used the latest version of the core plugin you would not need 

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.encodePassword = true

Turns out, that when i turned it on, every thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, make sure you have this line in your application.groovy.

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.encodePassword = true